# Add values to array in one line

Tags: python

How can I write this code in one-line?

```
aa = []
for s in complete:
    aa.append(s)
```

I know there are several solutions. I would really appreciate if you could write them down.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this (be care with strings):

```
aa.extend(complete)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
aa = list(s for s in complete)
```

or if u want to copy list u can do follow:

```
aa = complete[:]
aa = complete.copy() # same
aa = list(complete) # same
```

or just use '+':

```
aa += complete
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are awesome:

```
aa = [s for s in complete]
```

Comment: Thanks, was so close I had: `aa = [for s in complete]`

Comment: This does not append complete. Why not simply do `aa = complete`

Comment: @JohnSmith That's a syntax error, though. I find the [x for x in list] syntax somewhat awkward, seems redundant, but it makes sense when you want to add some logic to it: sayings = [country.saying for country in list_of_countries]

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj as the title of the questions suggests, I assume he wants to add values from a list to another. That's not exactly the same: he may want to add logic to 'filter' some values. But that's speculation on my part.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you just need to set `aa` equal to `complete`, just use

`aa = complete`

Answer (score 1):

I like to do such things with a list comprehension:

```
aa = [s for s in complete]
```

Though, depending on the type of `complete`, and whether or not you want to use package like numpy there may be a faster way, such as

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.array(complete)
```

I'm sure there are many other ways as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add values to array in one line, it depends how the values are given. If you have another `list`, you can also use extend:

```
my_list = []
my_list.extend([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend `aa`, use the `extend()` function:

```
aa.extend(s for s in complete)
```

or

```
aa.extend(complete)
```

If you simply wanted to equate the two, a simple `=` is fine:

```
aa = complete
```